# Why do some commands require su instead of just sudo to do?

Tags: bash, sudo

I thought that running a command with `sudo` was identical to logging in as the root user and executing the command.  However I have found a few commands that do not work with `sudo` but do work for `su`.

For instance,

```
sudo > mail.log
bash: mail.log: Permission denied
```

but actually typing `su` and executing the same command works.

Why is this?

Comment: See also http://serverfault.com/q/75522/126632

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at what you're doing with this command.

```
sudo > mail.log
```

`>` in command-line before redirect stdout try to truncate `mail.log` file. This operation is performed by a regular user (before your `sudo` without arguments starts). Probably a regular user does not have write access to `mail.log` file.

**Everything works as it should.**

If you need to sudo to execute the command and write it to a file type, use the following command:

```
sudo "some_command with operands > mail.log"
```

Comment: IIRC the redirection is attempted before sudo. This means that the original user attempts the redirection and fails (no permission). Your answer has the order of operations incorrect which makes the rest of it based on that order less than useful.  Don't forget also that `>file` can be used to truncate file.

Comment: [@is the English way](http://serverfault.com/users/9517/is-the-english-way) Thanks i will improve my answer.